# Move cursor (caret) to current view

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a command or extension that would move cursor to current view?
I have Visual studio keymap extension that allows to scroll text using ctrl up/down arrows but cursor goes out of view if I scroll more than 1 page.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+9",
    "command": "cursorMove",
    "args": {
        "to": "viewPortIfOutside"
    }
}
```